# What causes Windows 8 Consumer Preview to lock-up / freeze / hang in Oracle VM VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox

I've installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview to a virtual machine using Oracle VM VirtualBox (4.1.14). It works well except for occasional temporary lock-up / freeze / hang interruptions.

It will freeze for about a minute and then resume like normal for several more minutes before freezing again.

**Host**
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
16 GB RAM
Intel Core i7 (quad core, hyper threading, virtualization) CPU

**Guest**
Windows 8 Consumer Preview 64-bit
2 GB RAM
2 CPUs

How should I configure VirtualBox to run Windows 8 well?

[image: Windows 8 on VirtualBox]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Guest Additions is installed on Windows 8. I really suffered with Win 8 virtualized performance until I installed guest additions.

But if you plan on doing anything significant in Windows 8 I strongly recommend running closer to metal. I've been very happy booting to VHD http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's an early beta.  Its installed normally on my high end laptop and that freezes up every couple days too. Save often and be thankful that it reboots faster than Win7